# 'int' object is not subscriptable error even when object is string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
pct = pd.read_csv('PHYF111_PCT.csv')
pct.drop('S.NO',axis=1,inplace=True)
pct.fillna(0,inplace=True)
pct
cut = lambda x: x[:11]
pct['Email new']=pct["Email Address"].apply(cut)
pct
```

[image]

The image is a screen shot of the data frame I'm trying to work on.
I'm trying to remove the first 10 indices of the Email Addresses by using a lambda function. However i'm getting the error 'int' type not subscriptable. This code works fine on the 'Name' column.Why isn't the code working for Email Address as even they are strings.

Comment: You can do this with a [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) like so: `pct['Email new'] = pct["Email Address"].str[11:]`

Answer (score 0):

There is missing value in column "Email Address" and it was filled-in with 0. Look at line 494.